# Guardar el valor del evento Click en una variable

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Me encuentro programando para un practico un juego de preguntas en windows forms, las cuales tengo un textbox con la pregunta y 3 botones con las opciones.

La pregunta es como podría guardar el valor del click de cada botón en una variable (cualquiera) ya que los botones cambiarían de valor a través que pasan las preguntas. así utilizarlo en un if para comparar directamente y mostrar si corresponde a la repuesta correcta o no.

Por ejemplo:

```
//suponiendo que la sentencia fuera corercta
(boton1 == clikeado){   
    MessageBox.Show("Correcto");
}
else
{
   //resto de la botones 
   MessageBox.Show("Incorrecto");
}
```

La verdad es que no se como encarlarlo, gracias.

Comment: Puedes agregar un label oculto debajo de cada boton y en el evento onclick de cada boton asignarle el valor correcto o incorrecto a ese label y hacerlo visible, dependiendo de cual sea la respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad Tag del botón para guardar cualquier objeto. Digamos que tienes 3 botones y solo uno tiene la respuesta correcta

```
button1.Tag = false;
button2.Tag = false;
button3.Tag = true;

 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Tag = false;
            button2.Tag = false;
            button3.Tag = true;

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is Button)
            {
                Button boton = (Button)sender; //sender es el objeto que envia el evento, es decir el butón. 

                bool correcto = Convert.ToBoolean(boton.Tag); //Haces un cast para sacar el valor del tag 

                if (correcto)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Correcto");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrecto");

                }
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is Button)
            {
                Button boton = (Button)sender;

                bool correcto = Convert.ToBoolean(boton.Tag);

                if (correcto)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Correcto");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrecto");

                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is Button)
            {
                Button boton = (Button)sender;

                bool correcto = Convert.ToBoolean(boton.Tag);

                if (correcto)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Correcto");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrecto");

                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Gracias Alfredo. No conocia la propiedad tag para guardar valores. En cambio usaba el sender y comparaba si el boton habia sido presionado. De esta manera parece mucho mas facil manipular los botones. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que la respuesta correcta esta en el texto de tu boton, solo haria falta capturalo con **btn1.Text** , con este pequeño codigo podes asignar o traerte el valor del texto actual de tu boton.

En el caso que necesites de guardarlo en una variable, se me ocurren que para una facil manipulacion podes guardar tu valor en una lista.EJ:

```
List<string> respuestas = new List<string>();
respuestas.Add(btn1.Text);
```

Espero que te sirva, de todas formas, agrega mas informacion a tu pregunta si queres respuestas mas concisas

Comment: Gracias Lcs. Nunca use un list... deberia probar.. Te cuento: sguiendo investigando use un sender el cual asigna a una variable para saber si el boton habia sido presionado, luego comparo si el boton se presiono es el correcto guardo el valor en un contador. Creo una funcion para que cambie todos los text de los botones y la llamo mediante la comparacion.